# Get enclosure URL from RSS feed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rss

I've tried the other answers on this forum, but without any luck. I'm trying to extract the enclosure URL for each entry from an RSS feed (it contains the direct link of the mp3 audio), so I can create a page that will contain a built-in player for all audio.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var FEED_URL = 'https://www.spreaker.com/show/1720272/episodes/feed';

$.ajax({
  url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(FEED_URL),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $(data).find("item").each(function(i) {
      var URL = $(this).find("enclosure").attr("url");
      console.log(URL);
    });
  }
})
```

Here's an example of one of the items:

```
      <item>
            <title>Episode 2 - 7 Minute Leadership</title>
            <link>https://www.spreaker.com/user/paul_falavolito/epsiode-2-7-minute-leadership</link>
            <description>Why should anyone be led by you?</description>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">https://api.spreaker.com/episode/8296378</guid>
            <pubDate>Tue, 19 Apr 2016 13:16:50 +0000</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="https://api.spreaker.com/download/episode/8296378/episode_2_7_minute_leadership.mp3" length="0" type="audio/mpeg"></enclosure>
            <itunes:author>Paul Falavolito</itunes:author>
            <itunes:subtitle>Why should anyone be led by you?</itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>Why should anyone be led by you?</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:duration>713</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:keywords>motivation,business,leadership</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:image href="https://d3wo5wojvuv7l.cloudfront.net/t_rss_itunes_square_1400/images.spreaker.com/original/f71be8f6c859a4ce5669a83cbf3bcd31.jpg"/>
        </item>
```

You can see there's an enclosure URL that refers to an mp3. That's the URL I'm trying to extract.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't think `dataType: 'json'` is correct; that rss looks more like XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up getting the enclosure url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var feed = "https://crossorigin.me/https://www.spreaker.com/show/1720272/episodes/feed";

  $.ajax(feed, {
    accepts: {
      xml: "application/rss+xml"
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find("enclosure").each(function() { 
        var el = $.parseHTML($(this)[0].outerHTML);
        var url = $(el).attr('url');
        console.log(url);
      });
    }
  });
});
```